# Android Ovelay Button Call Popup Window but my pop up window can't close

Tags: android

I want to create as facebook chat hat app therefore i create overlay button.
After clicked that button popup window will show with data but i can't create with popup window with following code.

```
    windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point point = new Point();
    display.getSize(point);
    screenWidth = point.x;
    screenHeight = point.y;

    butGo = new Button(this);


    parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // Width
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // Height
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, // Type
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,// Flag               
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT // Format)
            );

    parameters.x = 0;
    parameters.y = 50;
    parameters.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

    windowManager.addView(butGo, parameters);
```

=========> Overlay Button
=========> Overlay Button Clicked call popup window

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      // Check Single Click
long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION){
iniPopupWindow();
if (dicPopup.isShowing()) {
   dicPopup.dismiss();
} else {
    dicPopup.showAtLocation(butGo, Gravity.BOTTOM, 100, -100);
}
}
```